# What's the rationale behind the data_class parameter?

Tags: symfony

Given the entities

```
User
Adress
```

and a one-to-one relationship between them, I was wondering why had to set

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) {
    return array('data_class' => 'My\Bundle\Entity\Address');
}
```

in the `AdressType` class. As otherwise an array instead of an entity is sent to the `User::setAdress(Adress $adress)` method when I wanted to merge the entities' forms from the `UserType`.

It seems weird to me that I have to state the entity and that this is not "assumed" by symfony2.

Can someone enlighten me why this design choice was made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AddressType should be handled as standalone FormType which can perfectly function on it's own.
How do you expect FormBuilder to simply guess which (if any at all) entity class to load for a generic form type?

I guess FormBuilder could look if the field with custom FormType corresponds to an entity field and that field is relationship entity and then remap array data accordingly to it, but seems like a huge overhead just to avoid writing data_class.